# vue.js single component set data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that I need to pull some data in through an ajax call. The component is called fine, and the data is returned in the ajax call but I cant assign it to the data in the template?

```
<template>

    <div class="class-hero" id="dashboard-hero" :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + last.content_image + ')' }">

        <div class="class-hero-overlay"></div>

        <div class="class-hero-container">

            <h1> {{ last.content_name }}</h1>
            <p> {{ last.content_description }} </p>


            <div class="class-stat">
                <div id="classesCirle" class="hero-class-progress"></div>
                <p>Modules</p>
            </div>
            <div class="class-stat">
                <div id="studentsCircle" class="hero-class-progress"></div>
                <p>students</p>
            </div>
            <div class="class-stat">
                <div id="tasksCirle" class="hero-class-progress"></div>
                <p>tasks</p>
            </div>

            <a :href="'/all-classes/' + last.content_name + '/' " class="button-resume"><p>Resume</p></a>

        </div>

    </div>

</template>

<script>

    module.exports = {
        data: function() {
            return {
                last:[]
            }   
        },
        mounted:  function() {

            axios.get('/custom_api/api_home_get.php?', {
                params: {
                  ID: 14
                }
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                this.last = response.data.currentCourses[0];
                console.log(response.data.currentCourses[0]);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });

      }
    }
</script>
```

Is this not possible? How can I set the data `last` to the ajax call I make in the `mounted`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate table in Vue template component from rest api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270522/populate-table-in-vue-template-component-from-rest-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this` inside the `then` function isn't the same `this` of your component, because on Javascript, the `this` keyword is bound to its parent function.

You can learn more about it [here](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/) and with [this](http://codepen.io/vfreitas-/pen/JEoYKY?editors=1011) example.

You can fix it with some ways:

1 - Using the `bind` method of the Function prototype. This will bind your outside `this` with your local `this`.

```
axios.get('/custom_api/api_home_get.php?', {
   params: {
     ID: 14
   }
})
.then(function (response) {
    this.last = response.data.currentCourses[0];
    console.log(response.data.currentCourses[0]);
}.bind(this))
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

2 - Using ES6 arrow functions (will produce the same effect as above)

```
axios.get('/custom_api/api_home_get.php?', {
   params: {
     ID: 14
   }
})
.then(response => {
    this.last = response.data.currentCourses[0];
    console.log(response.data.currentCourses[0]);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in your `.then(response)` function is the problem. `this` is a very confusing thing, even for experienced developers sometimes. Here's what's going on:

You are trying to set the value of a data property on the vue component, using `this`. Unfortunately, you aren't referencing the component data. You are actually referring to the `axios.get()` function. This is because `this` is bound to the object/scope in which it was called(the 'call-site'). By calling `this` inside the function, you are setting a property which does not exist.

Solutions:
As the prior comment says: `.bind(this)` chained to the end of the promise should fix it.

Alternatively, you could use `var that = this;` to bind it to the mounted scope:

```
mounted: function() {
const that  = this;

axios.get('url',  {
   // Code here
}).then(response) {
   const reply = response.data.currentCourses[0];
   that.last = reply;
   console.log("that.last: ",that.last," | reply: ", reply);
}).catch(function(error) {
   // more code
});
```