# VueJS2 Table: How to add a filter

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to use something like this following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270522/populate-table-in-vue-template-component-from-rest-api) to populate a table within a vue using axios.

How do I add a filter and search bar? I don't seem to be able to add `v-for="post in posts | filterBy search`. Where search is the v-model of a `<input>`. I saw documentation that this is not available in vuejs2. Instead of the `v-for` directive, what other directive(s) can I use in the `<table>` tag that would support `filterBy` in vuejs2?

- Is there another directive I can use with axios?
- If I have a structure json coming from a rest api, how I can use something like [vue2-bootstrap-table2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-bootstrap-table2) and add the value by parsing a json?

Answer (score 0):

`v-for` is the directive you should be using to display multiple items. Also note that the `search` you intend to use to filter is regarded as `data` by vue.js and whenever such data changes, vue.js triggers a response.

You could a `computed` property that gets updated once the search query changes.

```
computed: {
    filteredList: function () {
      return this.list.filter(function(){ 
        //select only what matches filter
      });
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, if for instance you get the filtered list from an asynchronous function call, say remote api, vue.js provides property `watchers`. In fact this is exactly how [VueBootstrapTable implements the filter](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue2-bootstrap-table/blob/master/src/VueBootstrapTable.vue#L396)

```
watch : {
  filterKey: function () {
    // filter was updated, so resetting to page 1
    this.page = 1;
    this.processFilter();
  },
  ...
}
```

To use VueBootstrapTable with remote data, you do not have to axios directly since, the component already uses it under the hood. However, you need to configure it to fetch remote data by adding this to your `data` property

```
ajax: {
  enabled: true,
  url: "http://localhost:9430/data/test",
  method: "GET",
  delegate: false,
  axiosConfig: {}
},
```

Then reference the the ajax config in your component declaration like

```
<vue-bootstrap-table :ajax="ajax" ....
```